# Do I need a backend for a firebase web app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am curious with all the features of firebase, cloud functions, and client-side authentication, Firestore, etc. options, does it make sense to even use a 'backend' with a firebase web app? The reason I am asking is that I started a project with a react app and a node.js backend rest API service. I started to realize that with all of firebases features, it might make sense to scratch my backend entirely. What are everyone's thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Now you can build server-less aps using power of firebase services https://towardsdatascience.com/go-serverless-with-firebase-5348dedb70e9

Comment: You can use firebase to skip backend programming, or even user firebase to setup a nodejs backend (functions). The bad thing about not using a backend is security, you would need to master firebase security rules to completely protect data.

Answer (score 9):

You can use firebase directly without a backend (if it is just a simple project) but i'd recommend you to use it with a backend to be more secure, since the backend lets you check the recieved data if it is fake or not correct, also in order to hide your firebase's api key and other stuff like that, i have a firebase app on github (with front-end of react and backend of nodejs+firebase) i can leave the link of the repo if you are interested to check it out, thanks

Comment: A liitle late... Can you drop the link of the Github repo, I am interested. Or any node+firebase app's...

Comment: https://github.com/salahmak/Covid-19-shopping-app-backend/blob/master/server.js
it is not that great tho, i wrote that when i was a beginner, so i don't recommend using it lol

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is definitely a very good option for you. Since you are adept at using Javascript, you can use the Firebase JavaScript SDK and your backend is up and running

Google’s Firebase offers the following:

A very robust authentication service(Currently supports Google, Facebook, Twitter, Github, Email/Password and Anonymous authentication).
Realtime Database
Storage
Hosting
Cloud Messaging
Notifications
Analytics

Hope this help...

Comment: Right. I know it is a good option. I am just curious if it makes sense to scratch my backend... Just have everything running on firebase through my frontend. Thanks